# How to connect to FTP server in nautilus in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: connection, ftp, 16.10

I want to connect to an FTP server on my Ubuntu desktop 16.10 but the option to do that from nautilus is not available as it was in Ubuntu 16.04.

What is the way to do that in Ubuntu 16.10?